# cluster_database TRUE/FALSE what does it mean in Oracle RAC?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-11g, rac

I have 3 databases on an Oracle RAC (two nodes) one database which is running with CLUSTER_DATABASE=TRUE on both nodes, the other two runs on each node with CLUSTER_DATABASE=FALSE

what does it mean the CLUSTER_DATABASE value?
and if it is CLUSTER_DATABASE= FALSE, is it as a normal single node Oracle Database?
what happen to the database instance that runs as (CLUSTER_DATABASE=FALSE) when the node is offline? dose it goes online on the other node or it goes offline as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the SIDs on all the nodes? Is this really the same DATABASE. For example you can have 3 node cluster having a single ASM on all the nodes, but database A is clustered on node1/node2. But database B runs only on the node 3.

The database B then is still started and stopped by the Clusterware, but is not clustered. You can also check output from:

```
ps -ef | grep -e lmd
```

The lmd process is started on clustered instances only.

EDITED: maybe I understand now. You do not have RAC database. RAC is active-active cluster. .i.e databases instances run on multiple nodes at the same time.

You have standalone instances guarded by Oracle Clusterware. So you have active-passive failover cluster. As described [here :Using Oracle Clusterware to Protect
A Single Instance.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/clusterware/overview/si-db-failover-11g-134623.pdf) Then you do NOT need the parameter cluster_database set to true. It only applies to RAC databases.

Comment: the SIDs are different on all of databases (instances) the Cluster is installed on Windows! and they all located on ASM...  when you say "but is not clustered" means of the node3 is down the the database B is down?

Comment: Of course they are different. But when you have SIDs: A1, A2 and B. Then A1 and A2 belong to a database "A" and "B" is standalone database. You can also execute `select * from gv$instance` and you will get status of all your instances within the database.

Comment: OK thanks ... so back to my main concern, what happen to B (not clustered) when the node goes offline?

Comment: check that docs. If configured properly the clusterware should assing virtual IP from one node onto another, than start the listener and the database on another cluster node.